# markdown to html via pandoc full page width

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc

I have a markdown file `test.md`

```
---
title: README TCC
numbersections: true
---

# README
sdfsafdasfdijmsldfnmlsnmkldfnmlsnmfdnmsaklm saldnmflasnfjlsanfjlnsajlfnjslnf sadfnasjlfdnlasd sdfsafdasfdijmsldfnmlsnmkldfnmlsnmfdnmsaklm sdfsafdasfdijmsldfnmlsnmkldfnmlsnmfdnmsaklm sdfsafdasfdijmsldfnmlsnmkldfnmlsnmfdnmsaklm sdfsafdasfdijmsldfnmlsnmkldfnmlsnmfdnmsaklm sdfsafdasfdijmsldfnmlsnmkldfnmlsnmfdnmsaklm
```

which I convert into an html file via `pandoc -s --toc ./test.md -o README.html --number-sections`

This is the resulting `README.html` viewed in chrome:

[image]

But I want to let the text span the whole page!

Within `README.hmtl` the style of body is specified as:

```
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 36em;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  hyphens: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  font-kerning: normal;
}
```

Adding `min-width:80%;` as an attribute, yields the desired behavior:

[image]

How can I make pandoc automatically generate a html that spans the whole page, when generating the document, i.e. include the `min-width:80%;` property?

Comment: I think this might be a result of the fake data you are using, since each "word" is so long, I think this layout might just be the result of line-wrapping. Have you tried with a more traditional lorem-ipsum style fake data with shorter words?

Comment: @DBS I adjusted my question, as you see, the text can span the full page, setting the right html style properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the below snippet anywhere in your Markdown document:

````html
``` {=html}
<style>
body { min-width: 80% !important; }
</style>
```
````

This will override the default `min-width` setting.